# gdb disassemble one line

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I want to disassemble only one particular line of code in gdb; to do this, I need the memory address of said line. How can I get the address of a particular line of code in gdb? Or better yet, is there a command in gdb to disassemble by line number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a break on the line you want to disassemble and then, you could try to get the current instruction with.

```
disp/i $pc
```

This always works for me, when I debug binaries with no debug info. Also one could simply get the current `pc` either by `print $pc` or `info registers` or simply use the `x` instruction.
e.g.:

```
x/10i address  //displays the first 10 instructions in assembly starting from address
```

or

```
x/10i register //displays the first 10 instructions starting from address stored in register
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `set disassemble-next-line on` to diassemble by line number.  Then use whatever technique you want to set a breakpoint at the specific line you want to view.